# Google Earth Api Change Image Contrast

Tags: javascript, image-processing, google-earth-plugin

Is there a way to do any sort of pixel manipulation on images loaded as icons or overlays in the google earth browser plugin?
I'm looking for something that would give the user a number of slide bar options that could change contrast, brightness, etc.
So `onChange` or `onSubmit` the icon would update:

```
icon.changeContrast(contrastVal);
icon.changeBrightness(brightnessVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, no.

You could do some HTML5 image manipulation using canvas or even CSS filters, but if you wanted it then fully integrated as a regular icon/overlay/what have you in Earth, you'd have to round-trip it to a server and back to the plugin (since the plugin runs in a separate process and it can't get access to javascript handles of images or load them from dataurls).